# Override nunique() or add a wrapper to it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with nunique is called by an empty groupby it ends with an error

```
>df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
>df.groupby(['A'])['B'].nunique()
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I want to add a simple check that if the groupby is empty just return an empty series.

I changed the def of nunique in python portable and added a check there that works:

```
def nunique(self, dropna=True):
    """ Returns number of unique elements in the group """
    ids, _, _ = self.grouper.group_info
    val = self.obj.get_values()

    try:
        sorter = np.lexsort((val, ids))
    except TypeError:  # catches object dtypes
        assert val.dtype == object, \
            'val.dtype must be object, got %s' % val.dtype
        val, _ = algos.factorize(val, sort=False)
        sorter = np.lexsort((val, ids))
        isnull = lambda a: a == -1
    else:
        isnull = com.isnull

    ids, val = ids[sorter], val[sorter]

    if ids.size == 0: ######Thats what I've added
        return Series(ids,index=self.grouper.result_index,name=self.name)

    # group boundaries are where group ids change
    # unique observations are where sorted values change
    idx = np.r_[0, 1 + np.nonzero(ids[1:] != ids[:-1])[0]]
    inc = np.r_[1, val[1:] != val[:-1]]

    # 1st item of each group is a new unique observation
    mask = isnull(val)
    if dropna:
        inc[idx] = 1
        inc[mask] = 0
    else:
        inc[mask & np.r_[False, mask[:-1]]] = 0
        inc[idx] = 1

    out = np.add.reduceat(inc, idx).astype('int64', copy=False)
    res = out if ids[0] != -1 else out[1:]
    ri = self.grouper.result_index

    # we might have duplications among the bins
    if len(res) != len(ri):
        res, out = np.zeros(len(ri), dtype=out.dtype), res
        res[ids] = out

    return Series(res,
                  index=ri,
                  name=self.name)
```

The thing is I can't change portable itself, I need somehow to override nunique or add a wrapper function that will be called when groupby(...).nunique() is called.
I looked online but couldn't find (nor understand) anything.
Sorry if it might be simple Q, but I'm a novice programmer so go easy on me :)

Thank you,

Comment: What's your pandas version? I just checked that version 0.19.2 does return an empty series for `df.groupby(['A'])['B'].nunique()` when `df` is empty.

Comment: Hi, my version is 0.18.1 and I did saw it was a known issue that was fixed in later versions, but updating the Pandas is problematic... Perhaps I can install the package.whl, do you know how can I find which package is it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What about using the apply function to add a condition to check the length of the group?

```
df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique() if len(x)>0 else 0)
```

Comment: Hi, first of, thank you for your help! That's a great solution but lambda is heavy on the performance and I'm trying to avoid it as much as I can...

Comment: In that case, you can just redefine the nunique function the way you want in your code and call it like df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(func=nunique) which should work. I think using the lambda function is probably a less messy way of solving the problem.